# Updaing track information when using iTunes COM Interface

Tags: vb.net, com, itunes

I am writing a program to control iTunes using the iTunes COM Interface and VB.NET. I am trying to figure out how to update labels in my program with the new track information when the track changes in iTunes. I haven't been able to figure this out. When the track changes, how do I update my labels with that new information? My program doesn't seem to know that the track changed. I try to update the information, but the program doesn't seem to get the new track information from iTunes. What do I need to do? I am using this method to update the labels:

```
Private Sub UpdateLabels()
    Label1.Text = "Current Track: " + track.Name
    Label2.Text = "Current Artist: " + track.Artist
    Label3.Text = "Length: " + track.Time
End Sub
```

I think the labels are technically being updated, but as I said before, I don't think the program is getting the new track information, so it doesn't appear that they changed. If I restart my program, it gets the new information and updates the label accordingly.

The documentation is [here](http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/main.html).

Comment: Where is Updatelabels called from? You will need something like an event handler or timer-based polling that calls it.

Comment: @Poul7 That's the thing. I think I need to setup the "ITEventPlayerPlayingTrackChanged" event and call "UpdateLabels" from there. But I have no idea how to set up this event so that I can call "UpdateLabel" from it. To answer your question, it is currently being called from the form load event, as well as my previous and next buttons.
http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/interface__IiTunesEvents.html#a3